# PHP array repeating values

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

In my custom `Moodle plugin` I get the *garages* for each *date*, where are they *booked*, so I should have a list like that:

```
Date1 - Garage 1
Date2 - Garage 2
Date3 - Garage 2
```

As you can see, one *garage* can repeat on different *dates*.

I get the garage names with this code:

```
$garagenames = array();
foreach ($garage as $rawgarage) {
        $venue = array();
        if (!empty($rawgarage->building)) {
            $venue[] = $rawgarage->building;
        }
        if (!empty($rawgarage->address)) {
            $venue[] = $rawgarage->address;
        }
        $garagename = implode(', ', $venue);

    $garagenames[] = $garagename;
}

function _remove_empty_internal($value) {
  return strlen($value)>1;
}

function remove_empty($array) {
  return array_filter($array, '_remove_empty_internal');
}

$dates_arr_clean = remove_empty($allsessiondates);
$rooms_arr_clean = remove_empty($garagenames);
$rooms_arr = array();//explode("/n", $garages);

$datesgarages = "";

foreach ($dates_arr_clean as $date) {
    if($garages_arr_clean)
        $datesgarages .= $date . " - " . array_shift($garages_arr_clean) . "<br />";
    else
        $datesgarages .= $date . "<br />";
}
```

The var_dump of `$rawgarage` is:

```
(stdClass)#65 (10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(8) "Garage1" ["building"]=> string(18) "HQ" ["address"]=> string(14) "1 Times Square" ["capacity"]=> string(2) "1" ["type"]=> string(8) "internal" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["custom"]=> string(1) "0" ["timecreated"]=> string(10) "1458557926" ["timemodified"]=> string(10) "1459842497" }
```

The problem is that the repeating values are not shown, so we become:

```
    Date1 - Garage 1
    Date2 - Garage 2
    Date3 - **missing** (Garage 2)
```

What I am missing in code in order to display the repeating values?

Comment: Your use of inline code markup for seemingly random words is very confusing. If you want to highlight stuff, use _italics_ or **bold**. Please [edit] your question and refer to the markdown help provided in the editor. Thank you.

Comment: Please post a var_dump of `$rawgarage`

Comment: Here is the var_dum `object(stdClass)#65 (10) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(8) "Garage1" ["building"]=> string(18) "HQ" ["address"]=> string(14) "1 Times Square" ["capacity"]=> string(2) "1" ["type"]=> string(8) "internal" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["custom"]=> string(1) "0" ["timecreated"]=> string(10) "1458557926" ["timemodified"]=> string(10) "1459842497" }`

Comment: @StartVader please edit your question to insert that information. Comments get overlooked and deleted.

Comment: @simbabque Anyone can edit posts on Stack Overflow, including you.

Comment: @Ian unfortunately I cannot improve the question, because I don't understand what OP wanted to say with the weird formatting. Instead, I chose to educate a new user, which seems to have worked. Teach a man to fish... :)

Comment: Please provide the raw value of $dates_arr_clean & $garagenames

Comment: $dates_arr_clean: `array(3) { [0]=> string(31) "5 April 2016 9:00 AM - 10:00 AM" [1]=> string(31) "14 June 2016 9:00 AM - 10:00 AM" [2]=> string(31) "1 March 2017 9:00 AM - 10:00 AM" }` and $garagenames: `array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(45) "Brooklyn garages, Brooklynsquare" [2]=> string(34) "World Trade Center, 1 Times Square" }`

Comment: You should really use SQL for this rather than code. What is the structure of the garages table and the dates table?